# Deleted config.php Authentication Unique Keys and Salts

Tags: wordpress, authentication, key, unique

I dont have any other copy of these Keys .What to do in this case ?
define 'AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this URL to generate new keys: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: In fact it didn't worked because i had changed the url of the site before from admin pannel of wordpress. But i solved this issue from the database. Changing the url caused this problem, i didn't figured out immediately but when i looked up into database i realised where the error was.